# Lambda & DynamoDB: "The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Can anyone figure out why this number string cannot be converted to a number!!

I have the following Lambda function which is taking a set of data being sent from API Gateway and then configuring it to save it to DynamoDB.

```js
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js.
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
// Set the AWS Region.
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

// Create DynamoDB service object.
var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({ apiVersion: "2012-08-10" });

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // response variables
  let body;
  let statusCode = "200";
  const headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  };
  // request parameters
  let params = {
    TableName: "users_amazon_profiles",
    Item: {
      "user_id": { "S": "event.user_id" },
      "refresh_token": { "S": "event.refreshToken" },
      "profile_id": { "N": "event.profileArray[0].profileId" },
      "country_code": { "S": "event.profileArray[0].countryCode" },
      "currency_code": { "S": "event.profileArray[0].currencyCode" },
      "account_info": { 
        "M": {
          "marketplaceStringId" : { "S": "event.profileArray[0].accountInfo.marketplaceStringId" },
          "id" : { "S": "event.profileArray[0].accountInfo.id" },
          "name" : { "S": "event.profileArray[0].accountInfo.name" },
          "type" : { "S": "event.profileArray[0].accountInfo.type" },
          "validPaymentMethod" : { "BOOL": event.profileArray[0].accountInfo.validPaymentMethod }
        }
      },
      "daily_budget": { "N": "event.profileArray[0].dailyBudget" },
      "timezone": { "S": "event.profileArray[0].timezone" },
    },
  };
  
//  request
  try {
    console.log("profileId:");
    console.log(event.profileArray[0].profileId);
    body = await ddb.putItem(params).promise();
  } catch (err) {
    statusCode = "400";
    body = err.message;
    
  }

//  dynamic response
  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers,
  };
};
```

And here is the JSON test object being used for testing:

```
{
  "user_id": "g490754-49b9-9079-c63aba5cccf6",
  "refreshToken": "Atzr|IwEBIMvPPWsTFHLgvbEhgUn30P57Kake_nfIgVa-6GJeIe9vsW38GdoDcpzCXIlqd6-82YdC8JISNxuQJQ5QREGmSX0YRu6qJ4zteznkqoaygCPk1ZqHE2jPhcbDuDZiGRNOWpis0pPpKaS9ylJsp2Vquwa5lM6Olu_qhRanp8iewCLmK-k4W8FkjA0aiiCqJPyfb7dsloXO-TGDPK8WXSoLREnzhucaO5Xn-TnwicZzKrq0mYBHyhzm1XNvEGmSiDm1cxkgFcQr0TvkVhyOoTeLuKz3Cw-1iAQg6rbaXiEvgo18ganZYO71vpv4jy5S91h5NVZwCgtG7tJ73A5DzOBdRXjjhke5xJ7HHEZQncQUPjE_R0gZBtsXpKfJVaaPjY925m-GCMbdhe9aFR0gKYlaDz-q-Nbo_I-vUA",
  "profileArray": [
    {
      "accountInfo": {
        "marketplaceStringId": "OKE9KIKX0DER",
        "id": "OI9FU2GLDTTWKS",
        "name": "Test Seller",
        "type": "seller",
        "validPaymentMethod": true
      },
      "countryCode": "US",
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "dailyBudget": "999999999",
      "profileId": "2591184040605621",
      "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    {
      "accountInfo": {
        "marketplaceStringId": "ATVERKIKX0DER",
        "id": "A3UJTRELDTTWKS",
        "name": "ACME",
        "type": "vendor",
        "validPaymentMethod": false
      },
      "countryCode": "US",
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "dailyBudget": "10000",
      "profileId": "999918498705620",
      "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    },
    {
      "accountInfo": {
        "marketplaceStringId": "ATVOIKIKX0DER",
        "id": "A3UJU6HLDTTWKS",
        "name": "Woolworths",
        "type": "seller",
        "validPaymentMethod": true
      },
      "countryCode": "US",
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "dailyBudget": "999999999",
      "profileId": "111184040605621",
      "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles"
    }
  ]
}
```

So basically in the Lambda function, we are looking at the `profileArray` which has three objects in it, and we are taking data out of the first object and putting it into the params that we are going to save to DynamoDB.

The items specifically that we are having trouble with is:
`"profile_id": { "N": "event.profileArray[0].profileId" },`

We can see that we are specifying this piece of data to be a number, and we are inputting it as a string (as we should be) and in the test JSON object, we can see that it is a string. However, when we run this function we get the response:

```
{
  "statusCode": "400",
  "body": "The parameter cannot be converted to a numeric value: event.profileArray[0].profileId",
  "headers": {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

This is crazy because that item is DEFINITELY a number. I have tried everything I can think of. You can see in the request I console logged the item just to make sure it is coming in correctly and yes, we get the following in the console log:

`2591184040605621`

One thing that I thought could be the problem is that the `profile_id` is the sort key of the DynamoDB table, so I made sure that the data type of this sort key is number, so that is not the issue.

Can anyone figure out why this number string cannot be converted to a number!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can not be converted because you are actually passing it as a string.

Remove the quotes (`"`) around the `profileId` from your JSON object where you are refencing the `event`.

```js
...
"profile_id": { "N": event.profileArray[0].profileId }
...
```

Comment: This was the correct answer but I was confused about WHY it was correct at first. The documentation does explicitly state that all the items should be strings when they are passed in without the document client, and the data type is explicitly specified with the datatype objects `{ "N": "number"}`. However what was happening was that because everything being passed in was ALREADY in a string format, I was adding a second set of quotation marks, so that DynamoDB was actually receiving `""NUMBER""`.

Comment: @NickC The documentation states the value should be a string. In your code, you have the value in a variable. The value is a string, so you need to pass in the value of that variable. Instead what you were doing is passing in the **name** of the variable. The AWS SDK was then taking that name and trying to convert it to a number, which obviously didn't work.

Comment: `"profile_id": { "N": "event.profileArray[0].profileId" }` - this will pass the string of `"event.profileArray[0].profileId"` as it is. It wont dereference the value of the `profileId`, because essentially you are hard-coding a string here. If you remove the quotes, than the values from the `event` will be taken.
This is basic Javascript, nothing really related to the Lambda.